# Docker service disable memory swap

Tags: docker, memory, docker-swarm

can i set “MemorySwap” and “MemorySwappiness” for docker service?
I would like to disable memory swap for docker containers (started by docker service) but i don’t want to disable it for host machine.
What means value of -1 at “MemorySwappiness”?

Docker version: 17.06.2-ce

Comment: Not possible yet. See: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34654

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is old, as it has no answer I have decided to post one.

Indeed, disabling memory swap is now supported by just using the option `--memory-swap` when creating the container. You simply have to set `--memory` and `--memory-swap` to the same value, according to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#prevent-a-container-from-using-swap).

This is how to do the same in a docker compose file:

```
services:
  mysvc:
    ...
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 500m
    memswap_limit: 500m
```

i.e. set the total amount of memory+swap that can be used to 500m, which - given there is only 500m of memory - means there is no need for swap so it will be effectively disabled.

For more information about memory swapping, visit [this page of the docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/) about constraining resource access.

Comment: This just seems to work on containers, but not on services. Trying to set this on a service returns `unknown flag: --memory-swap`.