# Set docker swap by creating a docker service in swarm mode

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, swap

I want to create a docker service in swarm mode and set the swap value of a container using docker-swap. However, docker is returning the message:

> unknown flag: --memory-swap

Looking at the documentation at docker https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/ , it says, that the flag can be set.

I have the following docker version:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.3
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.10
 Git commit:        a872fc2f86
 Built:             Tue Oct  8 00:59:59 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.3
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.10
  Git commit:       a872fc2f86
  Built:            Tue Oct  8 00:58:31 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.10
  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

To create the service, I use the following statement:

```
sudo docker service create \
--name servicename \
--replicas 1 \
--env DEBUG_LEVEL=0 \
--label com.docker.stack.image=imagename:latest \
--label com.docker.stack.namespace=namespace \
--label traefik.backend.loadbalancer.swarm=true \
--label traefik.docker.network=networkname \
--label traefik.port=80 \
--label traefik.webservice.frontend.entryPoints=https \
--reserve-memory=16M \
--limit-memory=128M \
--memory-swap=128M \
--limit-cpu=0.25 \
--network traefik-net2 \
```

I can create the service without the swap setting, however it is necessary to deactivate swap for different services.

Here I found a similar question, but the answer does not help: [Docker service disable memory swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47408800/docker-service-disable-memory-swap)

Edit:
When I want to update the swap on container level it is working:

```
docker update --memory-swap 128M containerId
```

When I want to update the swap on service level, it is not working and I get the same error:

```
docker service update --memory-swap 128M serviceId
```

Comment: The github issue in the linked question didn't answer your question? https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34654

Comment: I saw that link and also the referring link https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/37872. It seems like they have not merged the pull request so far. Therefore I is not usable for services so far. However is there another possibility? I do not want to run that on each (of the hundreds) new container manually. Can I run is somehow automatically as soon as the container is starting?